# Reading file into vector through function

Tags: c++

I am trying to read the txt file into the vector in function readIn. I cannot for the life of me get it to work. Either I get the following message "error: expected primary-expression before '&' token
     readIn(ifstream& infile, vec);" or the function isn't called at all.

```
int main() {

const int MAXSIZE = 100;
vector<int> vec (MAXSIZE);

ifstream infile;
infile.open("in9.3.txt");

readIn(ifstream& infile, vec);

return(0);
}

void readIn(ifstream& infile, vector<int> &vec) {
int a, count;

count = 0;
while (!infile.eof()) {
    infile >> a;
    vec.at(count) = a;
    count++;
}
infile.close();
vec.resize(count);
}
```

Comment: The call of `readIn()` in `main()` is wrong. (It's half a declaration and half a call.) It has to be `readIn(infile, vec);`.

Comment: When `main()` is compiled, function `readIn()` is unknown. (It's not yet declared.) Either move `main()` (including body) to the bottom or insert a declaration for `readIn()` before (or in) `main()`: `void readIn(ifstream&, vector<int>&);`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must not specify the type of the parameter when passing to a function.  What you have written is incorrect:

```
readIn(ifstream& infile, vec);  // error
```

Note that you are trying to pass the variable `infile` which is defined in `main`.  The compiler is complaining about the fact that you prefixed this with `ifstream&`.  The correct call is:

```
readIn(infile, vec);
```

Also beware that since the function is defined after `main`, there must be a function declaration somewhere *before* `main`.  It is not clear whether you did this or not, since you have not shown a complete program.  In any case, you can either move the whole definition before `main`, or just add this line:

```
void readIn(ifstream&, vector<int>&);
```

Comment: Thank you! I am just learning about file inputs and I was having trouble understanding the use of infile. This fix worked!

Comment: You're welcome.  Now would be a good time to review [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) in the help center.